# Get Mongoid as string in projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the below douments

```
{
    "page" : "A"
}
{
    "page" : "B"
}
{
    "page" : "A"
}
```

I am trying to get the mongoid as string using the below query during aggregation

```
db.getCollection('pos').aggregate({
  $group: {
        _id : '$page',
      name : { '$push' : {id:'$$ROOT._id.toString()'} }
  }    
})
```

**toString()** doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can just use _id , no?

Comment: i am getting this as object